# Can a clickable drop-down work with mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML menu, and when a user clicks on a menu item, a drop-down submenu appears. When the user clicks the menu item again, the drop-down menu closes.

I also want the submenu to close if the user's mouse leaves the element. The function below works with onclick, but the last few lines (mouseleave) does close the submenu, but then when I click the menu item again, the submenu does not re-appear.

Any advice on making this work?

Jim

```
// This function toggles CSS classes to display the submenu when clicked and
// to alternate the triangle arrow.
function abcSubMenuFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("abcsubmenu");
  var suby = document.getElementById("symbolRotate");
  if (y.className === "abcsubmenu" && suby.className === "symbolrotate") {
      y.className += " responsive";
      suby.className += " responsive";
  } else {
      y.className = "abcsubmenu";
      suby.className ="symbolrotate";
  }
  $("#myTopnav").mouseleave(function(){
      y.className = "abcsubmenu";
      suby.className ="symbolrotate";
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, move your jQuery event handler outside of your onClick function. Which will require getting the variables inside the scope of the handler.

Longer answer, if you want to keep everything packaged together try:

```
function abcSubMenuFunction() {
  let menu = document.getElementById('abcsubmenu');
  let submenu = document.getElementById("symbolRotate");

  if (menu.className === 'abcsubmenu' && submenu.className === 'symbolrotate') {
    menu.className += " responsive";
    submenu.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    menu.className = "abcsubmenu";
    submenu.className ="symbolrotate";
  }

  // you could also use .bind() here
  $('#myTopnav').one('mouseleave', function() {
    menu.className = "abcsubmenu";
    submenu.className ="symbolrotate";

  });
}
```

jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: Thanks, D Lowther.  This helps.